# Do I have apply for any transit visa when transitting overnight though NRT(Japan)?

Tags: japan, nrt

I have an Itinerary(Jan 2023) from India to USA booked through American airlines(AA) which has long layover(25 hours at NRT). AA didn't provide me with any details about the transit visa. Looking into the airport website, airport is closed from mid night to 6AM. I read at one place about shore pass which will be provided to passengers with next day connections and when I asked American airlines representative, he has no idea. Any idea? or similar experiences in recent days?